# GISC exercise 11.22d: Why is this stateful?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Exercise 11.22d of David Touretzky's "A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation" states:

"[...] Write a function `COUNT-BASES` that
counts the number of bases of each type in a DNA strand, and returns
the result as a table. Your function should work for both single-and
double-stranded DNA. Example: `(COUNT-BASES '((G C) (A T) (T A) (T A) (C G)))` should return `((A 3) (T 3) (G 2) (C 2))`, whereas
`(COUNT-BASES '(A G T A C T C T))` should return `((A 2) (T 3) (G 1) (C 2))`. [...]"

My solution:

```
(defun count-bases (strand)
  (labels ((flatten (tree)
           (cond
             ((atom tree) (list tree))
             (t (append (flatten (car tree))
                        (and (cdr tree) 
                             (flatten (cdr tree))))))))

    (let ((flat-strand (flatten strand))
          (cnt-list '((a 0) (t 0) (c 0) (g 0))))
      (dolist (el flat-strand cnt-list) 
        (incf (cadr (assoc el cnt-list)))))))
```

So the idea is to first flatten `STRAND` and then count with `assoc` and `incf`.

The problem is that this somehow retains the state of `cnt-list`, like so:

```
(count-bases '((g c) (a t) (t a) (t a) (c g))) ;; ((A 3) (T 3) (C 2) (G 2))
(count-bases '((g c) (a t) (t a) (t a) (c g))) ;; ((A 6) (T 6) (C 4) (G 4))
;; etc
```

I am aware that incf is de/con-structive, nonetheless cnt-list should reset after the function returns, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying a quoted list which is undefined behavior. If you want to construct a list to modify, you should use `(list ...)` instead of `'(...)`.

If you initialize `cnt-list` to `(list (list 'a 0) (list 't 0) (list 'c 0) (list 'g 0))`, it should work as intended.

Answer (score 4):

One can call `(copy-tree '((a 0) (t 0) (c 0) (g 0)))` to get a tree with fresh cons cells.

Answer (score 2):

I think that something Lisp people tend to do is to write over-general solutions to problems while not paying enough attention to domain knowledge.

Strands of DNA are, well, strands: they're chains of either bases or pairs of bases.  No strand contains both single bases and pairs of bases.  There are exactly four possible bases.  There are exactly two possible base pairs.

So while it's nice to be able to treat a strand as a general tree and flatten it, it's not actually a very good approach: it deals with objects which are far more general than DNA strands actually are, and also almost certainly does not detect errors in the data its being asked to process.

And while it's nice to use an alist to record the counts, and it certainly will be useful when we need to deal with alien DNA with some large number of bases, it's not actually very useful in this case.

Furthermore both these techniques make the program much slower and much consier than it needs to be.  (I have a suspicion one of the other answers also turns a linear problem into a quadratic one).  And so of course the old myth that lisp is slow will be reinforced, again, and that helps no-one.

(And of course, we all know that alien DNA is DAG-structured, so the tree-flattening approach, which seems like it might be useful, will horribly double-count the bases.)

Here's a solution which relies on some domain knowledge, and also does some checking of the data it gets.  You can call it with an optional 'be more fussy' argument which makes it be more fussy.  It's longer than the clever/general answers, but, well.  Inevitably it will have some idiot bug [it did].

```
(defun count-bases (strand &key (carefully nil))
  (let ((adenine 0) (thymine 0) (guanine 0) (cytosine 0)
        (double (consp (first strand))))
    (dolist (base/pair strand `((a ,adenine)
                                (t ,thymine)
                                (g ,guanine)
                                (c ,cytosine)))
      (typecase base/pair
        (symbol
         (when double
           (error "horrible aliens ahavere eaten my brain"))
         (case base/pair
           ((a) (incf adenine))
           ((t) (incf thymine))
           ((g) (incf guanine))
           ((c) (incf cytosine))
           (otherwise (error "aliens have horribly eaten my brain"))))
        (cons
         (unless double
           (error "aliens have eaten my horrible brain"))
         (when carefully
           (unless (member base/pair '((a t) (t a) (c g) (g c)) :test #'equal)
             (error "horrible brains have eaten my alien")))
         (case (first base/pair)
           ((a t) (incf adenine) (incf thymine))
           ((c g) (incf cytosine) (incf guanine))
           (otherwise (error "brains have horribly eaten my alien"))))
        (t
         (error "brains have eaten my horrible alien"))))))
```

Comment: this exercise is a good opportunity to name a function `fold-dna-strand`